# ¿Cómo contar varias palabras que aparecen en un archivo Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Tengo un archivo con un montón de números seguidos. Me piden contar las veces que aparecen las combinaciones 112, 113, 115, 116.

De manera individual ya lo he hecho y me da 232, 390, 442 y 201 respectivamente, que sumado da 1265. Pero si utilizo `grep -o -i nombre1 ARCHIVO | wc -l` sale 1191.

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma sencilla de contar las 4 combinaciones en una sola línea.

Sé que con grep puedo visualizar dónde aparecen con:

```
grep 'nombre1\|nombre2\|nombre3\|nombre4' ARCHIVO
```

Para contar también sé que se puede utilizar:

```
grep -o -i nombre1 ARCHIVO | wc -l
```

Pero si combino esos dos para contar varias palabras:

```
grep -o -i 'nombre1\|nombre2\|nombre3\|nombre4' ARCHIVO | wc -l
```

no me funciona ya que hay cadenas que son distintas pero aparecen en la misma línea por lo que el -o  y -i del grep no sirven en esos casos.

¿Alguien sabe la solución a este problema?

Comment: Creo que te entiendo, pero te entenderías más si pusieras un ejemplo de lo que tienes y de a lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: Iría bien un [example] con qué tienes, qué te da y qué quieres que te dé. Hice un ejemplo básico en local y sí me funciona bien. A todo esto, puedes hacer un poco de magia con Awk: `awk -F'112|113|115|116' '{tot+=(NF-1)} END{print tot+0}' fichero`. Le defines estos números como separadores y luego cuentas cuántos campos hay en total (si ";" es separador, "hola;adios" tiene dos campos, luego ";" está una vez)

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que usar bash-fu y hacer una corrida por palabra:

```
for palabra in palabra1 palabra2 palabra3; do
    echo $palabra: $( grep $palabra el-archivo.txt | wc -l )
done
```

Si lo que quieres es sumar las cantidades e imprimir un solo numero::

```
temp=0
for palabra in palabra1 palabra2 palabra3; do
    temp=$(( $temp + $( grep $palabra el-archivo.txt | wc -l ) ))
done
echo $temp
```

Como es un for, no estoy totalmente seguro de si corre el ciclo en un subproceso, y en ese caso el calor de temp no saldría del for. Si al correr la salida es 0, entonces toca hacer una pequeña modificación al script.

Comment: No tengo tanto nivel de linux. ¿Con comandos básicos no se podría realizar? Es para clase y llevo 3 dias comiendome la cabeza con esta pregunta.

Comment: @monica, esa es la respuesta. Reemplaza la lista de palabras que hay que buscar y el nombre del archivo sobre el que hacer el proceso

Comment: lo acabo de probar y esto muestra una lista con el conteo de cada palabra, no podrían salir sumadas?

Comment: ¿quieres un solo total Monica?

Comment: @AlvaroC. Sí, que haga el conteo de las veces que aparece cada palabra y luego las sume. Pero en clase aún no hemos visto for;do;done entonces no puedo utilizarlo

Comment: ¿se vale usar el comando sort ?

Comment: Y no te sirve entonces hacer algo como: echo $(($(grep 112 numeros.txt | wc -l)+$(grep 113 numeros.txt| wc -l)+$(grep 115 numeros.txt | wc -l)+$(grep 116 numeros.txt | wc -l)))

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad! Funciona perfecto y esto sí lo puedo usar. Mil gracias por la ayuda a los dos